# 8000 character limit in ASP Classic / SQL Server

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to do an update on a table in SQL Server 2008 R2, but the column writes only 8000 characters.

The column's datatype is set to `text`, but I have already tried to change to `varchar(max)` with no success.

I also used the `cast('variable' as text)` and `cast('variable' as varchar(max))`, also unsuccessfully.

When doing the same update by the SQL console (I made a response.write on the screen, copied and pasted it) or inserted more than 8000 characters manually, it works (through Microsoft Visual Studio).

```
sql_Up = "UPDATE ABVC_Eventos SET titulo_eve = '" & Strip(Evento) & "', cod_sup_eve = '" & Strip(cod_sup_eve) & "', cod_sup2_eve = '" & Strip(cod_sup2_eve) & "', texto_eve = CAST('" & Strip(texto_eve) & "' AS TEXT), WHERE id_eve = '" & Strip(Cod_Evento) & "'" 
set Rs_sqlUp = bco.Execute(sql_Up)
```

The 'Strip' function is for sanitization.

Comment: Repeat after me: I. will. never. again. build. SQL. like. that. - You **must** use parameterized queries under all circumstances. Please take a look here to learn [how to create and use query parameters  in ASP Classic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1092512/18771). After you have rewritten your code and the error still occurs, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Yep... Sadly it's an old legacy system and I can not do much about it.

Comment: @JairoFilho in which case, you can’t do much to fix it. Sorry.

Comment: @JairoFilho You can change the code, right? It's ASP, there is nothing that could stop you. So go and fix it.

Comment: I'll see if the client approves. Well, the client wants to migrate everything to PHP. I think I have one more argument now. Thanks guys!

Comment: @JairoFilho there is no quick fix, firstly you have to make sure the provider you are using in the connection string can support `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in the first place. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3112421/692942.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange problem with nvarchar(max) fields and Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112093/strange-problem-with-nvarcharmax-fields-and-classic-asp)