# Classic ASP ADODB results corrupted

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, adodb

I am migrating a Classic ASP application to a newer SQL Server database server.

The new server is a Windows 2019 Server (version 10.0.17763). I have an ADODB connection (version 10.0) to the SQL Server 2019 database (database is migrated from an older version).

It seems that the application runs *almost* perfectly, but among the dozens of ADODB queries that work fine is one that returns corrupted data.

UPDATED: It turns out that the only columns affected are indeed nvarchar(max) columns. As such, this is a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112093/strange-problem-with-nvarcharmax-fields-and-classic-asp).  My original question's detail follows:

If I run the stored procedure in SQL Management Studio, the results are perfect:

```
SELECT  dbo.[Staff.Reports].[Report Title], replace(dbo.[Staff.Reports].[Description],char(34),'') as RepDesc
FROM    dbo.[Staff.Reports] LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Staff.Reports Permissions] ON dbo.[Staff.Reports].[Report ID] = dbo.[Staff.Reports Permissions].[Report ID]
WHERE   dbo.[Staff.Reports Permissions].[Staff ID] = @StaffID
```

Returns:

| Report Title | RepDesc |
| --- | --- |
| Achievements Admin | Update OAA, and other Achievements |
| AdRef By Engineers | AdRef By Engineers |
| Adref Status Count | Ad Campaign report by ref no. |

etc.

However, when the identical query is run through the Classic ASP code, using the ADODB connection, the data returned becomes corrupted:

| Report Title | RepDesc |
| --- | --- |
| Achievements Admin | ] 0 |
| AdRef By Engineers |  |
| Adref Status Count | 0 |

Out of interest, the description column is an `nvarchar(max)` type.  I established the content of the output by logging it to a text output file - it's not an issue with the display of the data.

The output is the same number of characters, but they are mostly null and control characters.

I have tried deleting and recreating the query, but am at a loss as to what is happening.

Can anyone help, please?

Thanks for your interest, AlwaysLearning. All queries are run using the same 'GetRecordset' function, which is basically:

```
Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConnection.Open "Data Source=TheDatabase;UID=Fred;Password=" & strPassword
oConnection.CursorLocation = 3
Set CreateConnection = oConnection

Set objComm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objComm.ActiveConnection = CreateConnection
objComm.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
objComm.CommandText = cQuery
objComm.CommandTimeout = 1800

For iThisParameter = 1 to UBound(aParameters)
    Set objParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@par" & iThisParameter, adVarChar, adParamInput, 1024)
    objComm.Parameters.Append objParam
    objComm.Parameters("@par" & iThisParameter) = aParameters(iThisParameter)
Next
Set GetRecordset = objComm.Execute
```

Comment: _the description column is an nvarchar(max) type_ and _they are mostly null and control characters_ I think we'd need to see some of the Classic ASP code used around the SQL query. It sounds like it's assuming that that UCS-2 data in the `nvarchar(max)` column (where every other byte is generally going to be `0x00`) is some other character encoding and it's trying to render that using code page semantics.

Comment: Thanks very much for your thoughts. What you describe sounds exactly the sort of scenario. I have added the surrounding code to the question. Can I force the encoding within the Classic ASP code?

Comment: Run the exact same query in VBScript (or VBA, if you want the comfort of an IDE), just to rule out the thought that it might be ADODB's fault.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTF-8 String Classic ASP to SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866225/convert-utf-8-string-classic-asp-to-sql-database)

Comment: Hi Tomalak.  I have now changed the query to run directly from within the Classic ASP code, rather than call the SPROC.  This returns the corrupt data in exactly the same way.  I am pretty convinced that it's the code page now - I just don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @RS200Phil the duplicate explains it. It’s an encoding mismatch issue.

Comment: Thanks user692942. Guessing a bit, i tried adding "charset=utf-8" and "charset=ucs2" to the connection string. Neither was right, so I'll read on.
However, do you think I should look at how the encoding is on the SQL database, to ensure it matches the original format?

Comment: I really meant "take it out of ASP", not "run it in ASP in a different way". The point is to figure out what part of the mechanics are at fault here, because the solution depends on knowing. ADODB delivers *strings*, it does not deliver UTF-8 byte-streams. I don't think that reading how to decode UTF-8 in ASP Classic will help here, because that's likely not the issue.

Comment: I found this thread ["Strange problem with nvarchar(max) fields and Classic ASP"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112093/strange-problem-with-nvarcharmax-fields-and-classic-asp), which seems related. (Generally speaking, you have ported the database to a new SQL Server. If you converted an existing column to `nvarchar(max)`, convert it back to what it was - or use `ntext` and ignore the deprecation warning.)

Comment: That's a really interesting read - thanks again.  Lots of thoughts there.  I will try a few things in a while and let you know how it goes.  I need a couple of hours away from the screen now!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange problem with nvarchar(max) fields and Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3112093)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the modern, supported driver for ADO to connect to SQL Server.

[Using ADO with OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-ado-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks very much, David / Dan.  I'll give that a go.  I read the info in the link and it seems very relevant, so I'm hopeful!  Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: This was the solution :).  Thanks very much indeed to all of you.  Without the help of you all I don't think I would have found it. The issue is now fully resolved. Thank you all for your pointers.

Comment: @RS200Phil in which case mark your question as a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3112421/692942) which was answered 10 years ago.

Comment: Sorry 692, in my mind, when I searched the questions, I didn't find that one - I hadn't fully appreciated the issue until I had everyone's responses. I'll mark as a duplicate and hopefully it will help someone else.  With respect to it being a 10-year-old answer - I totally agree. The sooner these guys can offload their legacy systems the sooner I can fully retire :) With you on that one - and they're working on it.